# How to Manage back press in Fragments

Tags: android, fragment, android-fragmentactivity, back

I want to manage all fragment in back press.
When i click back press then open previous fragment and finish present fragment.

Answer (score 0):

you can manage back event like this in fragment:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

super.onResume();

getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
getView().requestFocus();
getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

            // finish your previous fragments here.

            return true;

        }

        return false;
    }
});
}
```

Comment: is this help you?